# PHP - Limit SQL results and show them by id

Tags: php, sql

How can you LIMIT SQL results and show them by order `id` once you refresh the page? For en example:

Refresh #1;
Show Query with id 20
Rrefresh #2
Show query with id 21
Rrefresh #3
Show query with id 23

etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the last showed id in a Session and than increment it on the next show.

to limit result you can use LIMIT:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT 5
```

to order the result use ORDER BY:

```
 SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean - how to show latest N items ordered by id in descendant order?

```
select * 
from table 
order by id desc
limit 0, 10
```

(N = 10 in this case)